# Check if regex pattern matching failed

Tags: regex, scala

I am working on a function that extracts a number at the beginning of the string. Given a string it should return a case class `Success` (containing the extracted number in `Int` and the rest of the string) in case it found a number at the beginning and a case Object `Failure` otherwise.

For that, I'm using regex pattern matching to match the number and the rest of the string into two separate variable. I then convert the number to `Int` and return.

The problem: when the string provided does not contain a number at the beginning, the pattern matching fail but I don't know how to detect that it fails, and when to return my Failure.

Any ideas ?

Here is my code

```
sealed trait Result
case class Success(expr: String, result: Int) extends Result
case object Failure extends Result

def extractNumber(str: String) : Result = {
  val pattern = "([0-9]+)(.*)".r
  val pattern(count, rest) = str
  if (pattern match failed) //How can I do that
    return Failure
  val number = count.toInt
  return Success(rest, number)
}

extractNumber("100banana") match {
  case Success(rest, nb) => println("sucess" + nb + ";" + rest)
  case Failure => println("failure")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pattern match on the string safely and extractor the required information if pattern matches.

In the below `pattern` can be used as an extractor. Read about Scala extractor pattern.

```
def extractNumber(str: String) : Result = {
  val pattern = "([0-9]+)(.*)".r
  str match {
    case pattern(a, b) => Success(b, a.toInt)
    case _ => Failure
  }
}
```

#### Lets check if it works on Scala repl

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait Result
case class Success(expr: String, result: Int) extends Result
case object Failure extends Result

def extractNumber(str: String) : Result = {
  val pattern = "([0-9]+)(.*)".r
  str match {
    case pattern(a, b) => Success(b, a.toInt)
    case _ => Failure
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Result
defined class Success
defined object Failure
extractNumber: (str: String)Result

scala> extractNumber("123192731qwlejqwlkje")
res0: Result = Success(qwlejqwlkje,123192731)
```

Looks like it works

Lets check what happens in case of failure.

```
scala> extractNumber("qwlejqwlkje")
res1: Result = Failure
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using deconstruction:

```
val pattern(count, rest) = str
```

Try using one of the [Regex API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) methods:

- `findFirstIn` returns an option -> if None, then this is "failure"
- `findAllIn` returns a `MatchIterator` that can tell info about the failure (for instance, `hasNext` or whatever)

An other way is to perform just as you do, inside a `try ... catch` and catch the *MatchError*.